# What is the need of a URI in namespace xmlns

Tags: namespaces, uri

xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"

Considering this namespace  prefix is `telerik` and the URI is http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation, what is the purpose of the URI. Is there any schema that is in the mentioned URI or is it just a logical name?

Could I give `xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.myexample.com`?

Answer (score 0):

The URI specifies where data types and elements in the schema come from.  You can reference types in as many other schema definitions as you like, and those definitions are defined by their namespace.

Here is a brief rundown of how schemas are defined: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp.